# How can I count the number of relationships each node has in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a graph db (neo4j) and cypher. My goal for this query is to first match every Pin that a given User has PINNED, and then count the number of LIKES each of those pins has. Currently I am able to return the total number of likes between all the pins, but this information doesn't help me when there are several pins. For example, if I run this query in my DB right now and there are 2 nodes with 2 likes and 3 likes respectively, my query will return "5". So I have no way of knowing how many of the likes belong to each pin. How can I write this query such that I get the number of LIKES for each pin?

```
MATCH (u:User {lastName:"Example"})-[:PINNED]->(z:Pin)
WITH collect(z) as cs
MATCH (:User)-[:LIKES]->(y:Pin)
WHERE (y) in cs
MATCH (a:User)-[r:LIKES]->(y)
RETURN COUNT(r), y
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you're going a little overboard on matches, we can simplify this.

```
MATCH (u:User {lastName:"Example"})-[:PINNED]->(z:Pin)
RETURN z, SIZE( ()-[:LIKES]->(z) ) as likes
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It looks like SIZE is the key here!

Comment: It's very easy to overlook, but so useful!